# How can I test in my device checks DNS CAA correctly and rejects TLS certificates that are signed by an unauthorized CA?

Tags: tls, dns, caa

I would like to know how I can test if my devices, or browsers<sup>1</sup> checks and applies [DNS Certification Authority Authorization (CAA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_Certification_Authority_Authorization) correctly. And if it does not, how I can enable it and enforce CAA to be checked and rejected or at least warned about.

I'm mainly interested in testing this on Windows, Linux and Android systems but information about testing this in Apple macOS or iOS is also welcome. Or if it's on the application level instead of the OS level I'm wondering about Firefox and Chromium based browser such as Google Chrome, Brave and Microsoft Edge.

<sup><sup>1</sup> If this still applies: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/180903/why-dont-browsers-check-caa-records-to-help-ensure-a-certificate-is-valid.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "correct checking of CAA by the device or browser". TLS clients like browsers are not in scope of CAA in the first place, it is only intended for certificate authorities. To cite from [RFC 6844](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6844) about the purpose of CAA:

> CAA Resource Records allow a public Certification Authority to
> implement additional controls to reduce the risk of unintended
> certificate mis-issue.

CAA records are also only checked at time of certificate issuance. The CAA record might change after certificate was issued, but while it is still valid. This means it would be wrong to check the CAA at any time after certificate issuance, which means clients like browsers would not be able to do it properly anyway since they cannot travel back to the time of issuance to check the CAA at this time.

This is also explained in the RFC itself, which therefore explicitly states

> Relying Applications **MUST
> NOT use CAA records as part of certificate validation**
> ... 
> CAA records MAY be used by Certificate Evaluators as a possible
> indicator of a security policy violation.  **Such use SHOULD take
> account of the possibility that published CAA records changed between
> the time a certificate was issued and the time at which the
> certificate was observed by the Certificate Evaluator**.

Comment: Thanks. It's even worse than I expected.

Comment: Is there another simple way of implementing CAA-like client validation? Or is the only alternative going full DANE/TLSA?

Comment: @BobOrtiz: What do you mean with "CAA-like"? If nobody provides the *real-time* information what CA should have issued the *current* certificate, then nobody can check if the certificate matches these requirements. And DANE/TLSA is not supported by browsers, so you cannot go full on it.

Comment: I'm thinking of this mainly in the light of self-signed CA's where you know and trust your own CA only as the CA for a particular domain. In this case, you would not want all other CA's to be able to give valid certs for that particular domain. Which you can achieve apparently by setting `0 issue "some-ca-domain.com"` which is still based on trusting the known CA's for checking it and complying with it on the moment of creation. But apparently the client won't bother to check or warn if another CA would sign it anyway. The same principle applies to non-self-signed certs.

Comment: @BobOrtiz: Why would you use self-signed CA with public domains? Browsers will not trust such self-signed CA unless one explicitly adds them a trusted. Or maybe I don't really understand your use case. What is it you are trying to achieve (no matter if CAA or DANE or whatever is the wrong or right tool for this)?

Comment: Private Nebula (overlay) mesh network. Basically all Edge clients and servers with virtual network adapters in a private IP range and Edge firewalls. Very gradual control. Public DNS to resolve to private IPs (not best practice but no good widely compatible alternative yet), and only thing leaking this way is a hostname and an internal IP that can't be accessed anyway, explicitly trusted self signed CA on all devices. Access of mostly web apps in browsers (so public DNS over private IP). No way to check and validate which CA the cert is from apparently and reject other knows trusted CAs.

Comment: @BobOrtiz: Using public DNS and public domains for private hosts/IP is surely edgy. Such edge cases are prone to cause trouble since they come with unexpected requirements on the rest of the infrastructure. Better avoid if possible.

Comment: I agree but the level of control and scalability over this software defined overlay network based on the noise protocol, is just really next level due to the centralized firewall control per device/adapter. It's basically a 'mutual TLS, mesh VPN'. I, so far have it running (Managed via defined.net) as one network between multiple cross platforms (Android, Windows, Linux) on remote and several datacenters cross continent. My main problem really on this network is DNS and HTTPS. Although the underlying connection is already TLS.